# Are My Little Pony: Friendship is Magic questions welcome here?

Tags: discussion, scope

So, as some of you have noticed, I've been asking a lot of questions about [friendship-is-magic](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/friendship-is-magic) on the site lately. It's because I've been watching the show in a marathon session on my breaks, after work, etc. I thought that since the show features anthropomorphized ponies, as well as fantastical elements such as dragons, magic, and pegasi, that the show was perfectly on-topic here.

However, I've noticed a lack of response to MLP:FiM questions in general, plus I received a number of downvotes on *all* of my MLP-related questions on succession today.

So, I'm asking the SFF community: are questions about *My Little Pony: Friendship is Magic* really welcome here?

Comment: Hi **Aarthi**. I downvoted some of your questions and flagged to close them as off-topic, then had an extensive discussion on meta about how I think a show about talking Ponies aimed at young kids (_not that there is anything wrong about it_; I like the Powerpuff Girls, for example) does not really belong to the F&SF genres. However, the rest of the community doesn't necessarily agree with me (which they have shown by also upvoting and answering your questions), so for now they are on-topic.

Comment: [cont'd] You may be interested about the more general question, [What are our boundaries](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1028/what-are-our-boundaries). You may want to chime in, since we have hardly arrived at a consensus.

Comment: @Aarthi You may want to take a look at my own doubts expressed earlier in this (now closed as duplicate) question: [Does the “My Little Pony” franchise belong in SF&F?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1781/does-the-my-little-pony-franchise-belong-in-sff).

Comment: I welcome MLP:FiM here, speaking for myself :) I don't think there is one work that gets to define fantasy. IMO, there are many facets to the genre.

Comment: Given the [extended discussion](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1028/what-are-our-boundaries) about MLP over on the meta question about our boundaries WRT children's works, I'm leaving this open instead of closing a duplicate.  It seems we need to discuss MLP *specifically*.

Comment: I've cleaned up the comments here, and on one of the answers below.  Keep the commentary a little more substantial and on-topic.

Comment: @AndresF. While I understand the logic to not including children's programming/media here, MLP:FiM has garnered a substantial periphery audience of adults. This is in keeping with a long tradition of shows with *good writing* getting due attention. Look at *Sailor Moon*, *Avatar: The Last Airbender*, *Space Cases*, *Justice League: Unlimited*, and other shows in the same vein. Comic books like *Tiny Titans* sell to more adults than kids! Ultimately, I see your argument, but it holds no water with me; PPG, Foster's Home, Dexter's Lab, and MLP:FiM gained broader audiences. They belong here!

Comment: @Aarthi Fair enough, and while I don't agree, I defer to the will of the majority. Keep in mind I like Dexter's Lab, but would vote against its on-topicness here as well ;) I don't buy the "has a large adult following" by itself, and I hope you see why: many other works of fiction also do, but aren't F&SF.

Comment: @AndresF. If someone asked questions about Sesame Street, I'd also vote them as OT, but I don't believe Muppets are off-topic, nor should MLP:FiM be. Ha, I think we're just going to end up in circles. Agree to disagree? *handshake*

Comment: Previous iterations: [Are children's literature and cartoons for children on-topic?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/683) ; [What are our boundaries?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/1028) This topic comes round periodically with no conclusive answer.

Comment: That there's continued discussion doesn't mean there's no conclusive answer. There's a small number of people who don't present any argument other than "I don't think it's fantasy", presenting no alternative definition of fantasy, and ignoring all the fantasy elements in the show. (Also, _Dexter's Lab_ not science fiction? If a show about mad _scientists_ dueling via mad _science_ isn't _science_ fiction, please tell me what it is so I can propose a Stack Exchange for it.)

Answer (score 14):

As they are squarely in the realm of Fantasy, they are as on-topic as The Last Unicorn questions, which is also about a talking horse. ;)

Comment: *waits for the inevitable plague of Mr Ed questions*

Comment: @dlanod: Is Mr. Ed's universe interesting, then?

Comment: Yes, Wilbur....

Answer (score 12):

I agree with Nathan and Gabe, but on your remark on:

> I've noticed a lack of response to MLP:FiM questions in general

While it may fit into the SFF area, it doesn't mean many people on this site watch it and hence be able to answer questions on it.  The answers will come if others interested in the program start using the site, or other users of the site become interested in it.

Comment: That, and there's just a lot of things that remain unanswered in the cannon, since the show is more about character growth than exploring the world (like, say, either series of Avatar) or exploring the characters (Bleach maybe?).

Answer (score 4):

There are certain users who are opposed to them, but since there is no good reason not to allow the questions, they are on topic and welcome.

Comment: @AndresF. Stop sniping in comments, post an answer that argues your case.